Easiest way to add drop shadow to Chapter Names in LyX?
I'm using LyX. I'm hoping to do a small thin drop-shadow on the chapter titles.  I can change the colors and fonts, but the only package I can find that does drop shadows is the shadowtext package.  I'm stuck at figuring out how to get fncychap or secsty or something to call shadowtext since I don't really TeX.  It's like I found a screw that fits the hole, but it's a torx head and I can't find the screwdriver.

Can you please add your .lyx file (.lyx !) as you would do with code? It's plain-text. So we can dowload and inspect your best approach in Lyx. Thank you

Document →
Settings ... →
LaTeX Preamble . The type:
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} % just to see the margin
\usepackage{shadowtext}
\shadowoffsety{.25em}
\shadowoffsetx{.25em}

OK to return to the main screen.
Now you must insert the chapter name with raw LateX code usind a Evil Red Text (ERT) box.
To be sure of put the ERTbox in the right place, make a normal chapter name "foo". If you do not want shadow text in table of contents and headers, now insert a Short Title (contextual menu or Alt+A1) and change the new  "foo"  by "whatever you want". Then select the old "foo" with the mouse and do  Ctrl+L. This must make the ERT box around "foo" (and nothing else). Now replace "foo" by:
\hspace{-.35em}\protect\shadowtext{Whatever with shadow} 

The \hspace is because \shadowtext has its own ideas of when it is good insert spaces. This happen also in normal text (see example below). You may need adjust that negative space in your document.
The command \protect is needed to use \shadowtext inside the chapter, i not needed in normal text (side note: to me have to need this command is like a warning that I am forgetting the valuable KISS principle).
Now the screen should look more or less like this:

And the PDF will be:

As you can see, in plain text also insert spaces before, no matter if it close to another word, or it is starting the the paragraph, with or without indentation. This is not a LyX or LaTeX issue, but of the design of this package.
